# Is spring @transactional thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I used `@Transactional` on one of my class and used it in a multithreaded environment? As I understand it will be executed in a thread local environment and is thread safe.

Now my use case is that it is withdrawing the amount from an account ? could there be a case of overdrawing if the account amount read is dirty ? I am not sure if it would be safe to be the way as it is now or I need to synchronize my functions.

Any advice will be highly appericiated.

Comment: Spring uses the underlying database implementation for transactions, so they are as thread safe as the underlying database can be.

Comment: Transaction isolation is a different issue from thread-safety.

Comment: Nathan is right. Look in Locking mechanisms provided by your database and your DB acces Java API (JPA, JDBC, etc...)

Comment: @Nathan,David How to achieve transaction isolation in JPA or JDBC any pointers or starting points ? Could you please suggest some good reference materials to read ?

Comment: @Naresh Kumar Look Select For Update, Optimistic Lock and Pessimistic Lock. they are different way to address your need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @davidhxxx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set your transaction isolation level to protect from dirty reads from the database, not worry about thread safety.  The database takes care of the "dirty read" aspect of this question - not Spring's threading model.