# Is the Ranger REST API Synchronous?

Tags: rest, hdfs, apache-ranger

I am using the importPoliciesFromFile API call to constantly replicate changes from one ranger instance to another. I see the importPoliciesFromFile will delete and recreate the policies with a new policy id. Will this cause any impact on authorization or how ranger works? I am imagining in my head that there won't be a policy for a split second due it deleting and then a client won't be able to be authorized or denied access. Or is it synchronous meaning, does it stop all other code execution and user interaction until the call returns?

Answer (score 0):

The [method](https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/master/security-admin/src/main/java/org/apache/ranger/rest/ServiceREST.java#L2219) you mentioned `importPoliciesFromFile` is in a [class](https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/master/security-admin/src/main/java/org/apache/ranger/rest/ServiceREST.java#L166-L167) with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation;

```
package org.apache.ranger.rest;

@Path("plugins")
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ServiceREST {

...

    @POST
    @Path("/policies/importPoliciesFromFile")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
    @PreAuthorize("@rangerPreAuthSecurityHandler.isAdminOrKeyAdminRole()")
    public void importPoliciesFromFile(...) {

    }

}
```

Please see the comments and the answer here [Is spring @transactional thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38487099/12974735). Looks like spring relies on its underlying database when it comes to "thread safe" and "dirty read".